# User defined type variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write 3 user defined type variables which need to be associated with each other like this;

```
Type tdrivers 
    Strfirstname as string
    Strsurname as string 
    Intage as integer
End type

Type Tcars 
     Strmake as string 
     Strmodel as string 
     Lngcc as long
     Driverid() as tdrivers
End type

Type T_Race
     Strlocation as string 
     DteRacedate as date
     IntYear as integer
     CarsID() as Tcars
End Type

Sub CreateRace()

Dim myrace() as T_Race

'Variables to hold integer 'values at runtime
Dim A as integer 
Dim B as integer
Dim C as integer 

'this line redims myrace ok
Redim myrace(A) 

'This line doesn't do anything 
'When I try to redim the 'carsID() array nested inside 'the myrace(A) like so;
Redim myrace(A).carsID(B)

'This line obviously does 'nothing either 
Redim myrace(A).CarsID(B).driverid(C)
```

I need to be able to assign races to the myrace() array and then assign cars to each race they have taken part in and then drivers to cars they have driven. So the carsID() must be nested within myrace() and driverid() nested within carsID()

Once I know how to redim carsID() in can then redim Driverid() which is nested further within.

If I make all the arrays fixed with a constant value such as 8 then the sub runs ok and all races, cars and drivers are nested correctly. Its the redim on nested dynamic arrays that is failing. Hope this makes sense. Can anyone help. Thanks

Comment: Did A, B have values before you try ReDim? What would you expect after ReDim  x(0)?

Comment: Yes A,B and C variables all have values assigned before the redims are done. Only myrace(A) gets redimensioned on its own but fails when;

Comment: Continued. CarsID(B) doesn't get redimensioned when nested  like so;   redim myrace(A).carsID(B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you have to `ReDim` *every* sub-array individually. The following example initializes all sub arrays and prints them at the end:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    
    ReDim myRace(5)
    
    For i = 1 To 5
        ReDim myRace(i).CarsID(5)
        For j = 1 To 5
            ReDim myRace(i).CarsID(j).Driverid(5)
            For k = 1 To 5
                myRace(i).CarsID(j).Driverid(k).Strfirstname = Chr(k + Asc("a")) & Str(i) & Str(j) & Str(k)
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ' Now print it
    For i = 1 To 5
        For j = 1 To 5
            For k = 1 To 5
                Debug.Print myRace(i).CarsID(j).Driverid(k).Strfirstname
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
        
End Sub
```

Comment: That makes sense now. Thanks so much for your reply and also the way in which you have explained it with an example. I will try it when back at work. Once again many thanks, thank God for experts like you to give novices like me help with practical examples and most websites don't explain everything fully when learning.

Comment: @RichieG Remember to mark the answer if it helps you so others can find it too

Comment: Friendly hint to make code fully reproducible: all three array declarations should be inserted either within the Example procedure or in the modules declaration head ( `Dim myrace() As T_Race`, `Dim CarsID   As Tcars` as well as `Dim DriverID As tdrivers`) :+)

Comment: Paul ogilvie, Your example to my question. When you redim each sub array do you need to use the preserve redim rather than just redim. Surely if you just redim alone each previous element will be lost as you loop through the array elements?

Comment: @RichieG, sorry for my late reply. If the arrays contain data, then you should use `Redim ... Preserve` so the existing data will be preserved.